# How to make a JavaScript or PHP conditionally redirect?

Tags: php, javascript, html, redirect

basically the page receives varaibles via the url `http://sitename.com?c1=xxx&c2=yyy`.

I want to redirect to one link if `c1` is less than `40` and otherwise go to a main link.

How do I program something like this?

Comment: Just make sure that if you use PHP for this, you buffer your output (see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), because if ANY output is sent before your redirect instructions, the redirection won't work - the headers will have already been sent.

Answer (score 1):

using php you use

```
Header("Location: theurltoredirectto.com");
```

the javascript solution would be

```
window.location = "http://www.theurltoredirectto.com/"
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, it’s essentially:

```
<?php
$c1 = int($_GET['c1']);

if ($c1 < 40)
    header('Location: http://new-location');
?>
```

After executing this code, just exit the script.

Comment: @Breezer Typo. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
if ($_GET['c1'] < 40) {
   Header("Location: http://sitename.com/onelink");
} else {
   Header("Location: http://sitename.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use `top.location.href='http://your.url.here'` or `window.location.href=...`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you'll want to use this code at the top of the script, *before* anything that outputs data to the page (such as echo, print, etc), as headers must be sent before any other data:

```
<?php
if (is_numeric($_GET["c1"]) and $_GET["c1"] < 40) { //Checks if the c1 GET command is a number that is less than 40
    header("Location: /path/to/page2.php"); //Send a header to the browser that will tell it to go to another page
    die(); //Prevent the script from running any further
}
```

You can set the `/path/to/page2.php` bit to anything that you would usually use for an `<a>` tag.

I don't recommend doing redirects in JavaScript or HTML, because if someone clicks Back in their browser, they'll be taken back to the page and be re-redirected to the next page.

Ad@m

Comment: @Breezer Sorry, my bad, I've fixed it now.